# How to send only POST-data (via Button click) in webView without following link

Tags: javascript, android, html

I load a webpage in a webView. In onPageFinished(..) i run some javascript code, which finally clicks a submit button. So the webView sends Post data and get an answer and loads a new page. That works fine, but i dont need the new page, its just unnecessary network load. I only need to submit the data.

So is it possible to send only the submit without loading the new page? I know that i can send post data with HTTPConnection, but i dont know the header consistence exactly, so i cant set the params. Is there any possibility with JS/Webview to abort?

**Edit:** I cant override onPageStarted() in my WebViewClient and perform a view.stopLoading(), because the new URL is still the same. But the site appearance is quite different. So i have to stop loading before

HTML of the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="savechanges" class="btn btn-primary" value="Speichern">
```

and three aditional lines above

```
<input type="hidden" name="uid" value="390">
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_jevents">
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="dash.listprojects">
```

which meaning i dont know (site is made by Joomla)

Comment: why vote down.. comment!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a "virtual form" and submit it, like:

`var $form = $("");`

... on click:

```
 $form.submit();
```

Hope this helps

Ops its removing my html from inside $form, inside the jQuery selector there should be a form like "form method='post' action='{someurl}'" with angle braces opening and closing properly

Comment: sorry, but i dont understand your answer :( what is someurl? the actual url? and could you please explain the syntax? Do you mean var $form = ("form method='post' action='http://www.google.com'");? then $form.submit() produces TypeError "$form.submit is not a function" Sorry i'm beginner with jQuery

Comment: it should be $form = ("<form method='post' action='http://google.com'>");

Comment: still error "$form.submit is not a function" please look at updated question